# shiny-server behind HAProxy load balancer, session persistance

Tags: r, cookies, shiny, load-balancing, haproxy

I'd like to ask for help with achieving application level persistence on a HAProxy load balancer. In our setup there is one load balancer running HAProxy and several backends running Shiny Servers with an identical R Shiny application. (All backends are connected to the same database.) In order to achieve persistence I use cookies inserted by the load balancer as described in this post: https://www.haproxy.com/blog/load-balancing-affinity-persistence-sticky-sessions-what-you-need-to-know/ (as in the "Session cookie setup by the Load-Balancer" part)

Once the cookies are introduced one's browser is always redirected to the same backend until the cookies are cleared. This is not the required behaviour as it is too 'sticky' - all consecutive sessions are redirected based on the cookie. The load balancer should use the load balancing algorithm for every new session, however I cannot follow the post to the part about "Using application session cookie for persistence" as Shiny apps don't use them. I'm stuck at this point and would be grateful for any insight or sharing of experience.

I've noticed there is a session ID in the URI of the http requests, like so:

`Request URI Path: /[our_shiny_app]/session/e75cc0c2efff0ac7650eef1616a1f7eb/dataobj/clicked_features_tab`

Would that be of help by any chance?
Or should I make use of the web-sockets?

Will be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: When you say "The load balancer should use the load balancing algorithm for every new session" you need to tell the load balancer how to be aware of the different shiny sessions based on what is in the server reply. I mean at one point the server will send the shiny session ID to the client (but the question is in which part of the reply exactly ?)  and that's where HAProxy should pick it and use it.